# Customizing table view (UITableViewStyleGrouped) design

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I'd like to change default grouped table view's appearance to something similar to this screenshot's table. Need to change cell's border style, shadow and radius, section header & footer font color and table's background color/image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

get reference from here: http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

it may help you

Comment: Though it is not the PO want's but gives good detail about tableview customization.

Comment: - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;

...and similar methods for footers. I've got this, but still don't know how to customize appearance of cells (border & it's round, shadow etc)

Comment: ...now got it. Just need to change cell.backgroundView and cell.selectedBackgroundView.

Answer (score 1):

I recently published a project on GitHub, showing how I styled a grouped table in one of my apps: https://github.com/randomsequence/GroupedTable